# Dynamic Code Snippet Display In Javascript

Tags: javascript, code-snippets, google-code-prettify

I am writing a JS function:

```
showCodeSnippet(fileName)
Input: Local File Name 
Output: Display Code in HTML
```

I know about the security constraints which restrict accessing local files in browser, but managed to create a workaround solution.

Please consider this Code (working on Firefox 57.0, 64-bit):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>

async function showCodeSnippet(fileName) 
{        
    const response = await fetch(fileName);
    const text = await response.text(); 

    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var domString = "<pre class=\"prettyprint\">" + text + "</pre>";
    var html = parser.parseFromString(domString, 'text/html');  
    document.body.append(html.body.firstChild);
}
</script>


<script>
showCodeSnippet('Code.txt');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code.txt contains some sample C++ code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int n;
     cout << "Enter an integer: ";
     cin >> n;

     if ( n % 2 == 0)
            cout << n << " is even.";
     else
            cout << n << " is odd.";
     return 0;
}
```

Output HTML Page:
[image]

Problem Statement:

Syntax Highlighting is NOT working.

Tried:

- Google code-prettify
- Prism Highlighter

These highlighters work fine in case of static code under  tags in HTML.

Can someone please provide any hint -  root cause of this problem or shall I think in any other direction to achieve this type of functionality ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a difference in Chrome. When i Use Firefox, i get the same problem as you. Hold on, i will check some things :)

When you add `PR.prettyPrint();` after your appending, the pretty-print will also work in FireFox. seems that the automated repaint is not supported in FireFox by the code :(